# PowerShell script for sync an azure website and the source code stored in Dropbox

Tags: powershell, azure, web, dropbox

I store my website source code (php) on Dropbox.  I usually use the Azure portal to sync the content. Does anyone have a PowerShell script for doing the job?

Comment: do you have any code that you have started on?